# Pivot on datetime with matching multiple column

Tags: pivot, datetime

I have the following table with column school, state, subject and timedate.
[image]

I would like to have output with column school, state, act and english

- filter subjects to only Act and English
- pivot table to match school and state

[image]

I did tried but all queries are not work. Hopefully someone may help. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Quickly:

```
select school, state, Act, English, History
from (select school, state, subject, timedate
      from data) as pivotdata
         pivot (max(timedate) for subject in (Act, English, History)) as P
```

Should work

[image]

Comment: can you show a picture of the result of this query? just to see if it matches the expected result